# How to not inherit a variable in C++ classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

With C++ classes, you can have a derived class inherit a variable from its parent class. How can I define the derived class so that `var2` is not inherited in `derivclass`?

```
class mainclass{
public:
    int var1;
    char var2;
    void test(){
        cout<<var1<<var2<<endl;
    }
}
class derivclass : mainclass{
public:
    void test(){
        cout<<var1<<var2<<endl;
        //want a compiler error here that var2 is not defined
    }
}
```

Comment: Make it `private`.  You can't avoid inheritance if the member is `public`.

Comment: if you define it as `private` in `mainclass`, then `derivclass` won't be able to touch it, but it will still *exist*

Comment: private keyword would do.

Comment: What's the downvote about? I can't yet see who it was, can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The canonical way to prevent a member from being inherited in C++ is to declare it `private`. Derived classes that try to access it will then throw a compiler error. It would look like this:

```
class mainclass{
public:
    int var1;
    void test(){
        cout<<var1<<var2<<endl;
    }
private:
    char var2;
}
class derivclass : mainclass {
    public:
    void test(){
        cout<<var1<<var2<<endl;
        //compiler error here; var2 is not accessible
    }
}
```

This is the most straightforward way to achieve what you're asking for.

Comment: I think you have `var1` and `var2` reversed in your example.  `var1` would be inaccessible in your example.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks. Point is I want to make the non-inheriting variable available from the outside of `mainclass`. If I define a getter and setter as `inline`, will that induce overhead?

Comment: @tomsmeding: So you want the variable to be accessible from outside `mainclass` to everyone *except* `derivclass`? I don't think that's possible; if a member is public, or has a public getter, then everyone can access it, including derived classes. Or would it satisfy your needs if the derived class can access the variable but only through a getter?

Comment: No, not really. I want that you can access the value in `mainclass` (from outside), but that you won't be able to access that value in `derivclass`. So what I want is that the variable is available in `mainclass` but not inherited to `derivclass` so that `derivclass` just doesn't have it.

Comment: @tomsmeding: I don't think there's a way to define that kind of access. Anything that gives outside code access to `var2` will also give `derivclass` access to `var2`, because `public` means everybody, including derived classes.

Answer (score 5):

You can make it `private`. But you probably shouldn't.

The fact that it shouldn't inherit some stuff from Base means it probably shouldn't inherit from Base directly at all.

Instead create another base class and make the two classes inherit from that base.

```
class Baseclass{
public:
    void test(){
        cout<<var1<<endl;
    }
protected:
    int var1;

}

class mainclass : public Baseclass{
public:
    char var2;
    void test(){
        cout<<var1<<var2<<endl;
    }
}

class derivclass : Baseclass{
public:
    void test(){
        cout<<var1<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give you a point back as your answer is fine.  Don't know why someone down voted this.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer, but the best thing to do is to always make your data members private, and define getters and setters as needed.  See "Effective C++" by Scott Meyers.

Comment: @Dima but this is different. In this case you can't even get or set the private variable. It is not directly accessible to Derived in any way.

Comment: Well you get +8 out of the deal anyways.  Keep up the good work!

Comment: @user2280716, I agree with your approach of factoring out a common superclass.  I simply disagree with your first statement. :) You should always make your data private.

Comment: Nah, this advice goes against what many (most?) C++ experts advise. You should make all variables `private` and define a well-defined interface that’s `protected` to access the state in the base class as needed – but “as needed” actually means “as little as possible”. Everything else violates [*Tell, Don’t Ask*](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask).

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else says, you can make it private in the base class and then it's not accessible in any sub-classes.  However, as @Dave says, it will still exist inside the base class.  If you don't even want it to exist as a variable that's hidden from the subclasses, then you'd have to take it out of the base class.  Assuming that the variable is needed for something, you'd then have to make a new subclass which contains that variable.

Answer (score 0):

A derived class inherits every member of its bases. Full stop. You cannot selectively inherit parts of a base class.

Making a variable private does not prevent inheritance. The variable is still there, but under ordinary circumstances it is not accessible. With various friendship games you can make it accessible. Maybe part of the confusion here is caused by Java, where private members are not inherited. That is,

```
struct Base {
private:
    int i;
};

struct Derived : Base {
};

Derived d;
d.i = 3; // error: d.i is not accessible
```

If `i` was not inherited, the error would be that `d` has no member named `i`.

EDIT: another, perhaps more meaningful, example

```
void f();

class Base {
    void f();
};

class Derived : Base {
    void g() {
        f(); // error: Base::f is not accessible
};
```

With Java's rules, the call to `f()` would be okay, and would call the global `f()`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Uh, nothing. What about you?

Comment: Well not sure how you’re getting the idea that Java can magically remove members when inheriting. Of course in Java a derived class inherits *all* its base’s members.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - I didn't say that it could magically remove members when inheriting.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “not inherited”, then?

Comment: @KonradRudolph - sure. It's everything from the second paragraph to the end: the name is not present in the derived class. That's the difference between C++ and Java here: in C++, the names of private members of base classes are present, but not accessible; in Java they do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In response to all the other answers (and possibly piggybacking off of Stochastically), you can switch the main and derived class, where the new main class would have all the member values that you want in the original derived class, putting the unneeded ones in the new derived class(aka the original main class)

Observe:

```
class newMainClass{
public:
    int var1;
    virtual void test(){ //added virtual here so there aren't two definitions for test()
        cout<<var1<<var2<<endl;
        //want a compiler error here that var2 is not defined
    }
}

class newDerivedClass : public newMainClass{
public:
    char var2;
    void test(){
        cout<<var1<<var2<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the "out of the box" thinking, but this is not really a solution. Rather, it is a way to avoid the problem. Reversing the inheritance relation is not always possible.